# Dynamically change text in Keynote slide using Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, keynote, iwork

What i am wondering is, is there a way to load up a keynote slide, have the slide run an applescript(which reads a text file) and takes that information and uses it to populate text fields on that keynote slide?

Example: Open Keynote presentation. Play the presentation. When we get to slide #4, launch the applescript to get the info that you need from the text file, then populate the text field.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but the answer is **yes**. You can use Applescript to run through the presentation and pause on whatever slide you like. The boxes for inserting text are called "text items" and you can set their contents through the `object text` property. I found [this site](https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/text-item.html) very helpful (link goes to the text item page)